# Como inserir dados em tabelas relacionadas usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Pesquisei bastante mais não achei nada concreto com `PDO`, ouvir falar nessa função `last_insert_id` mas não tenho noção de como aplicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja um exemplo de como inserir um bairro:

```
public function insert (Bairro $bairro){
     $this->connection =  null;
     $teste = 0;
     $this->connection = new ConnectionFactory();
     $this->connection->beginTransaction();
     try{
         $query = "INSERT INTO bairro 
                   (CD_BAIRRO, NM_BAIRRO, CD_CIDADE) 
                   VALUES 
                   (NULL, :bairro, :cidade)";
         $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro->getNmBairro(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindValue(":cidade",$bairro->getCidade()->getCdCidade(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->execute();
         $teste =  $this->connection->lastInsertId();
         $this->connection->commit();
         $this->connection =  null;
     }catch(PDOException $exception){
         echo "Erro: ".$exception->getMessage();
     }
     return $teste;
}
```

Espero que ajude a ter uma noção